# ModernCV package - PDF doesn't work

Tags: moderncv

I have some Problems with the ModernCV package. What I have written so far is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             
\moderncvcolor{green} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.7cm}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{Joe}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               
\address{Here}{or}{There}
\phone[mobile]{xxxxxxxxxx}                  
\phone[fixed]{yyyyyyyyyy}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\cventry{2560}{Champ}{University}{Elswhere}{}{what}

\end{document}
```

If I know use `\makecvtitle` or `\begin{cvcolumns}` I get no output anymore. I already tried to change the `moderncv.cls` class file as it is purposed in

> https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/commit/c91b6ca77c7fe422f8519a433d13db6c3c715384

But it still doesn't work. Has anyone an idea how to solve it? I would like to have a Header at my CV.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Which version of `moderncv` do you use? Check the log file please and add this information to your question. Also add the error messages you get to your question ...

Comment: please make your example be an example of the error, where do you add `\makecvtitle` for example?